# The passive voice with prepositional objects

Tags: passive-voice, objects, direct-objects, indirect-objects, prepositional-passive

The question concerns changing of the form and place of the direct object and prepositional objects in a sentence after it was reverted to the passive voice.
For example let's consider the following couples of active/passive sentences:

```
1. He sent for the doctor. 
2. The doctor was sent for.
```

and

```
3. He sent her to a hospital. 
4. She was sent to a hospital.
```

Now let's consider the combined grammar structure

```
5. He sent her to a hospital for the doctor.
```

How do the passive voices look like here? What form do the objects ( *to a hospital, for the doctor, her*) assume there?

Will it be correct to write like

```
6. Her was sent to a hospital for the doctor.
7. The doctor was sent for to a hospital.
8. The doctor was sent for to her.
9. The doctor was sent for to a hospital to her.
```

How should be modify these sentences in case they aren't correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in this answer, I am using the word **[patient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patient_(grammar))** to refer to the noun at the start of a passive voice sentence.

Sentences 1 and two use the phrasal verb **send for** with **the doctor** as object/patient, whereas sentences 3 and 4 simply use the verb **send**, with **her/she** as the object/patient.

In the passive voice sentences, 6 is almost right: as in sentence 4, when **her** becomes the patient, it becomes **she**.

> **She** was sent to a hospital for the doctor.

The other sentences don't work because **she** was sent to the hospital, not the doctor, so you can't use the prepositional phrase **to the hospital** if **she** does not appear in the sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if "He sent for the doctor to a hospital" is correct, why can't it be revert to the passive like as "The doctor was sent for to a hospital" where "sent for" is a phrasal verb as well?

Comment: _The doctor was sent for to the hospital_ means that the hospital asked the doctor to go there. The meaning of _He sent her to a hospital for the doctor_ is unclear. Did he send her at the doctor's request, or so that she could see the doctor there?

Comment: "the hospital asked the doctor to go there". Shouldn't it expressed by preposition *by* (not *to*)?? *The doctor was sent for by the hospital*

Comment: Well, yes, that's how I would normally say it; but to me, the only logical meaning of _the doctor was sent for to a hospital_ would be _the doctor was summoned and asked to go to a hospital_.

Comment: Ok, my original question is getting clearer for me. Now I wonder how to modify this sentence (The doctor was sent for in the hospital) to convey my appropriate meaning.

Comment: @xyz "the doctor at the hospital was sent for".